# How do I write a byte array to a file in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, arrays, logcat

This is my code to create a file.

```
public void writeToFile(byte[] array) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        String path = "/data/data/lalallalaa.txt"; 
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path); 
        stream.write(array); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
    { 
        e1.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

When I try to send my file to my server by just calling the path `String path = "/data/data/lalallalaa.txt";`

I get this logcat error message:

```
03-26 18:59:37.205: W/System.err(325): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/lalallalaa.txt
```

I don't understand why it can't find a file that is "supposedly" created already.

Comment: don't forget to close the stream afterwards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure the file is created already?

Try adding this:

```
File file = new File(path);
if (!file.exists()) {
  file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was correct. I was not actually creating a new file. Did not know about that method and didn't know that it was necessary. Thanks

Comment: @EGHDK The docs implicitly say that the file will be created: "If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown."

Answer (score 20):

I think you'd better add close function of FileOutputStream for clear code

It works me perfectly

```
try {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

/data/data/ is a privileged directory in Android.  Apps can't write to this directory or read from it.

Instead, you should use `context.getFilesDir()` to find a valid filename to use.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown if either the file does not exist or if you are trying to write to a file that is read-only. Also try using full path name and see if the same exception occurs (to check if you gave the correct relative path).