# Android bluetooth client receive xml

Tags: android, xml, bluetooth

I'm new at android development and I'm creating simple bluetooth app that can receive `xml` file and save `xml` file values to database. But how can I receive xml file from bytes array? Is it possible? After searchinf I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878150/how-do-i-write-a-byte-array-to-a-file-in-android) and based ont that question I try to save byte array to file. But how I need to test it? I can't find my file in my phone.

```
                  case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    try {
                        String path = activity.getFilesDir() + "/myFile.xml";
                        Log.d("MuTestClass", path);
                        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
                        stream.write(readBuffer);
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
class Utils{

    public static InputStream openFile(String filename) throws IOException{
        AssetManager assManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;
        is = assManager.open(filename);
        return new BufferedInputStream(is);
    }

    public static byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len = 0;

        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

like this:

```
try {
     Utils.readBytes(Utils.openFile("something.xml"));
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```